# Can we have a function without a name in C?

Tags: c

I was digging [SnoopSnitch](https://opensource.srlabs.de/projects/snoopsnitch)'s source code when I found in one of it's libraries this line, written in C :

```
(_s, m);
```

*_s* and *m* are both structures so what can it be ?

PS: Check the end of [this file](http://pastie.org/10778097) to see the actual source code.

Comment: That is not a function call, just an evaluation of `_s` then `m`.  Possibly useful in debugging.

Comment: It's a comma operator.

Comment: also note that functions in C are generally referred to as functions, not methods, method usually being known as a function belonging to a class

Comment: Some C implementations _do_ allow for anonymous functions, but what you've posted isn't one of them.

Comment: @n.m. I just understood what is the comma operator [thanks to this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c), but in that case... why aren't they using the returned value ?

Comment: To silence compiler warnings perhaps. Hard to tell without more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C hasn't "methods" at all, it has functions.

In any event, the code you present is not a function call, it is an expression statement.  The parentheses serve their precedence-overriding grouping function, albeit unnecessarily, and the comma is the comma operator, which evaluates both operands, and has as its result the value of its second operand.

Inasmuch as the result is unused and the comma's operands are simple variable names, the statement overall has no side effects.  The only purpose I can think of is the one @chux suggested in comments: to provide a statement where you can insert a breakpoint for debugging, and especially for examining the values at that point of the two variables involved.